# "No module named numpy" in CDAP python transformation

Tags: python

I want to use numpy library inside CDAP transformation process. But whenever I add the library it shows the error "No module named numpy" where I've to copy the library code?
[image]

Comment: Do you have numpy installed on your Python?

Comment: yes i am using python 3, but CDAP python runs on version 2. I don't know where to put the library files.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have *two different version* of **Python** installed on your machine:

- Python 2
- Python 3

You probably installed the **numpy** library on Python 3 but not on Python 2: since CDAP runs on Python 2, it will try to `import numpy` and if the library is not present you will experience the error you're reporting.

In order to solve this issue just open the command prompt and type:

```
pip2 install numpy
```

This should install the numpy library on your Python 2 distribution and you should be good to go.

Speaking in general, you might want to always do something like:

- `pip install packageName` if you only have one version of Python on your machine
- `pip2 install packageName` to install packages on your Python 2 distribution
- `pip3 install packageName` to install packages on your Python 3 distribution

*Just for the sake of clarity*, the standard path to Python 2 external libraries should be located on your machine somewhere like:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

This is the path where you will want to make sure, after a proper numpy installation, that the library of interest has actually been installed.

Let me know if this solve the problem, the pip command name might slightly change depending on the Python 2 version you have.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks @Employee I'll try this. thanks, i hope it will work

Comment: I found that CDAP using python 2.5.2 version. but in my machine python 2.7 exists

Comment: also found jython is running behind this as standalone. please guide me how to install libraries in jython standalone

Comment: In order to do so, could you please edit your question clarifying what's the system setup and the application architecture?

Comment: @muTheTechie were you able to find a solution to installing libraries in jython for CDAP Python Evaluator?

Comment: yes the latest CDAP version has the new plugin which resolves the issue... the new plugin using host machine's python libs